# compare 3.C with 3.B and 3.D

Tags: c#, string, string-comparison

I want to do the comparison of multi-part alphanumeric strings.

I receive a string which contains the sw version currently running in the system.

I want to do some operations only if the system is running on a certain sw version or later.

e.g. If system is running sw version 3.D or later (3.E, ..) I do some operations. If system is running lower sw version (3.B, ..) I do not do it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear at all. Please clarify it.

Comment: A is oldest and D is newest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an `IComparer<string>`, e.g.:

```
class VersionComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string a, string b)
    {
        // omitted error checking for brevity
        var sa = a.Split('.');
        var majorA = sa[0];
        var minorA = sa[1];

        var sb = b.Split('.');
        var majorB = sb[0];
        var minorB = sb[1];

        if(majorA == majorB)
            return minorA.CompareTo(minorB);

        return majorA.CompareTo(majorB); // assuming a single letter of always the same case
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
var comparer = new VersionComparer();
Debug.Assert(comparer.Compare("2.C", "2.D") < 0);  // 2.C is older
Debug.Assert(comparer.Compare("2.D", "2.D") == 0); // same
Debug.Assert(comparer.Compare("2.E", "2.D") > 0);  // 2.E is newer
Debug.Assert(comparer.Compare("3.C", "2.D") > 0);  // 3.C is newer
Debug.Assert(comparer.Compare("0.A", "0.B") < 0);  // 0.A is older
```

Note that it would be better to store your version number in suitable type, something like:

```
class Version
{
    public int Major {get; private set;}
    public string Minor {get; private set;}

    public Version(string s)
    {
        // omitted error checking for brevity
        // assuming a single letter of always the same case
        var sa = s.Split('.');
        Major = int.Parse(sa[0]);
        Minor = sa[1];
    }

    public static bool operator <(Version one, Version another)
    {
        if (one.Major == another.Major)
            return one.Minor.CompareTo(another.Minor) < 0;
        return one.Major< another.Major;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Version one, Version another)
    {
        return !(one < another);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Version one, Version another)
    {
        return one.Major == another.Major && one.Minor == another.Minor;
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Version one, Version another)
    {
        return !(one == another);
    }

    public static bool operator >=(Version one, Version another)
    {
        return (one > another || one == another);
    }

    public static bool operator <=(Version one, Version another)
    {
        return (one < another || one == another);
    }
}
```

and a quick check:

```
Debug.Assert(new Version("2.C")  < new Version("2.D"));
Debug.Assert(new Version("2.D")  > new Version("2.C"));
Debug.Assert(new Version("4.C")  > new Version("2.D"));
Debug.Assert(new Version("4.C")  == new Version("4.C"));
Debug.Assert(new Version("4.C")  >= new Version("2.D"));
```